# Checking message value in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am working with a Google ReCaptcha on a Django site and would like to check the value of the error messages.  If the value is 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.' then I would like to show an error message under the ReCaptcha.  However, the way that I have this set up is not currently working.

```
<div id="g-recaptcha-error">
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      {% if message is 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.' %}
        <span style="color:red;">{{ message }}</span>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

How do I check the actual value of the recaptcha message?  There could possibly be additional errors so I don't want this to show up if the value is different.

When I include this below it shows 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again. test' So I know the message is correct.

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <p>{{ message }} test</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
{% if message|stringformat:"s" = "Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again."  %}
```

Comment: That was what I tried first.  I just tried it again and it's still not working.

Comment: have you tried stringformat also i.e. message|stringformat:"s"

Comment: I have not.  How would that be used in this situation?

Comment: {% if message|stringformat:"s" == "Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again."  %} and also there must be space before and after ==

Comment: Well there's the answer right there!

Comment: Updated my answer. Glad that works for you.